# How do I create a temporary table out of this SQL merge statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL query in Access that is supposed to find duplicates and update a field based on that. It is giving me the "this query is not updateable" error. I read online that I need to create a subquery that creates a table? I'm not sure how to go about this at all honestly.

This is my query:

```
UPDATE work T INNER JOIN
      (SELECT DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
          FROM work                      
          GROUP BY DIVISION, FIPS_COUNTY_CODE, LAST, SUFFIX, FIRST, TITLE, BIRTHDATE
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          ) AS S
      ON  T.DIVISION = S.DIVISION
      AND T.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE = S.FIPS_COUNTY_CODE
      AND T.LAST = S.LAST
      AND T.SUFFIX = S.SUFFIX
      AND T.FIRST = S.FIRST
      AND T.TITLE = S.TITLE
      AND T.BIRTHDATE = S.BIRTHDATE
SET T.BAD_CODES = T.BAD_CODES  & 'D'
```

Answer (score 1):

Reasons why a Query or Recordset is not updateable
There are many reasons why your data may not be updateable. Some are pretty obvious:

•   The query is a Totals query (uses GROUP BY) or Crosstab query (uses TRANSFORM), so the records aren't individual records

•   The field is a calculated field, so it can't be edited

•   You don't have permissions/rights to edit the table or database

•   The query uses VBA functions or user defined functions and the database isn't enabled (trusted) to allow code to run

Some reasons are less obvious but can't be avoided:

•   The table being modified is a linked table without a primary key.

o   For certain backend databases (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server), Access/Jet requires the table to be keyed to make any changes. This makes sense since Access wants to issue a SQL query for modifications but can't uniquely identify the record.

Less obvious are these situations:

•   Queries with some summary fields linked to individual records and the individual records still can't be edited

•   Queries with multi-table joins that are not on key fields

•   Union queries

Copied from http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html